# Что делает Амур со стрелой? Если нацеливает, то какой предлог далее?

Tags: выбор-слов, управление, точное-словоупотребление

> Амур в очередной раз натянул для него свою стрелу.

Ой, и не *нацеливает в*. По смыслу: сражает.

Comment: А можно мало-мало контекста?

Comment: Димка распустил свой павлиний хвост и выступал теперь сразу перед пятью очарованными дамами. Он был прекрасный рассказчик! К тому же в поворотные моменты своих историй он обычно вскакивал и пересказывал все в лицах. И главное – талантливо. Мы хохотали до упаду! Ну точно герой лучшего из всех возможных мультфильмов. И вот тогда Амур в очередной раз натянул для него свою стрелу (СТУКНУ, ЗА НАТЯНУТУЮ СТРЕЛУ. САМА ПЕРЕДЕЛАЕШЬ?). И с одной из прелестниц Дима уехал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из контекста:
*К тому же в поворотные моменты своих историй он обычно вскакивал и пересказывал все в лицах. И главное – талантливо. Мы хохотали до упаду! Ну точно герой лучшего из всех возможных мультфильмов. И вот тогда Амур в очередной раз натянул для него свою стрелу. И с одной из прелестниц Дима уехал.*

1. Я бы переставила местами предложения.
   ...и пересказывал все в лицах. И главное – талантливо, ну точно герой лучшего из всех возможных мультфильмов. Мы хохотали до упаду!
2. **Вот тогда и метнул Амур в очередной раз свою стрелу. И — с одной из прелестниц Дима уехал.**

Не пойдет? (Автора оберегаем изо всех сил!) Вот классик и литературовед.

*Ему мерещились татарские всадники, которые, изогнувшись, припали к гриве коня, готовые **метнуть стрелу из огромного лука...*** (В. Ян. Батый)

*Она пришла перед короля, но еще не успела миновать первой двери, как от лица его королевского величества **Амур метнул свою стрелу**...* (А. Н. Веселовский [Александр]. Избранные статьи)

Comment: Натянуть стрелу и метнуть ее - это разные вещи. Натянутая стрела - это потенциальная угроза, выстрела может и не быть. Именно такая ситуация в тексте - амурчик только прицелился.

Comment: Мне показалось, что амурчик не только выстрелил-метнул, но и "конкретно" попал в героя: _и с одной из прелестниц Дима уехал._  Да и Галина пишет: "По смыслу: сражает".

Comment: Уехать - это еще не полюбить (это я так думаю), поэтому и о стрельбе говорить пока рано. А что было дальше, мы не знаем, в книжку не заглядывали.

Answer (score 1):

1) Можно написать так: ***Амур в очередной раз нацелил на него свою стрелу.***

Неплохой вариант.

НАЦЕЛИТЬ, -св. 1. что на кого-что. Направить на какую-л. цель (оружие, орудие). Н. орудие на крепость. Н. ружьё на медведя.

2) Можно оставить авторский вариант: ***Амур в очередной раз натянул для него свою стрелу.***

Конечно, ***натянуть стрелу*** – это переносное значение. В действительности он установил стрелу и  натянул тетиву. Но такие выражения встречаются, например:

Эти слова повисли в воздухе. **Амуры туже натянули стрелы**, готовясь к выстрелу, дабы запустить для этих двоих новый жизненный круг. Ведь всё ещё может быть. https://ficbook.net/readfic/7901965